# Docker stack healthcheck - use extension fields

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-swarm, docker-stack

i need to add healthcheck on my own docker stack, i'm using some extension fields in order to optimize my docker stack and reuse those field variables.

Now, for testing health of my services, i need to do a specific API call passing the token api as parameter, the token is defined as extension field.

How i can use this value inside the healthcheck definition? i've tried with `*` and `**`, also passing it as environment variable and using the `$${myvar}` notation, but no luck.

Here it is my docker stack:

```
x-var: &third-party-api-token
  "API_TOKEN_HERE"

services:
  nginx:
    image: *baseline-nginx-image
    environment:
      <<: *common-env-variables
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "-X", "GET", "-H", "Host: my-host", "http://wsgi_server:8000/api/healthcheck?token=**third-party-api-token"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - wsgi_server
    logging: *default-logging
    deploy: *deploy-mode-workers
```